# Decode base64/UTF-16LE using C

Tags: c, base64, decode

My problem is trying to decode a base64 / UTF-16LE string. The result of this decoding is always the first character. If you decode the string to utf-8 / ascii / windows1252, then the result is correct.

Can anyone have a ready-made solution?

The standard code from the internet that I use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    b64_decode_string("SABlAGwAbABvAA==");
    
    return 0;
}


char base64decode_lut[] = {
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 62, 64, 64, 64, 63,
    52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
    15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
    41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64,
    64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64
};
 

void base64decode(char *src, char *dest, int len)
{
    int i=0, slen=strlen(src);
    for(i=0;i<slen&&i<len;i+=4,src+=4)
    { 
        char c1=base64decode_lut[*src], c2=base64decode_lut[*(src+1)], c3=base64decode_lut[*(src+2)], c4=base64decode_lut[*(src+3)];

        *(dest++)=(c1&0x3F)<<0x2|(c2&0x30)>>0x4;
        *(dest++)=(c3!=64)?((c2&0xF)<<0x4|(c3&0x3C)>>0x2):'\0';
        *(dest++)=(c4!=64)?((c3&0x3)<<0x6|c4&0x3F):'\0';
    }
    *dest='\0'; // Append terminator
}
 
 
int b64_decode_string(char *source)
{
    int dest_size;
    int res;
    char *dest;

    dest_size = strlen(source);
    dest = (char *)malloc(dest_size);

    memset(dest,0,dest_size);
    base64decode(source, dest, dest_size);
    printf("Decode: %s", dest);
}
```

Comment: We are not a coding service, and requests for off-site resources are off-topic here, so no, we will not provide a ready-made solution.

Comment: In any case, a Base-64 decoder does not emit a character sequence, but rather a *byte* sequence.  If that result happens to express character data according to some particular character encoding, and if you want a result in a different encoding, then you'll need to transcode the result after base-64 decoding.

Comment: First of all: what does exactly work badly? What do you mean with _"The result of this decoding is always the first character"_? By providing the `"SABlAGwAbABvAA=="` what is the output? What would it be the expected one?

Comment: An altogether different issue may be in play if the input data, which *can* be considered character data, are expressed in UTF-16 (any variant).  In that case, you need to be careful to treat the characters as the 16-bit units they are, not 8-bit units.

Comment: Of course, a third possibility is that you have UTF-16 data that have been Base-64 encoded, and you are successfully decoding them back to the original UTF-16 form, but then mishandling the result.  In particular, if you expect the result of your Base-64 decoding to be a sequence of UTF-16 code units, then the chances are poor that `printf("Decode: %s", dest);` is a suitable way to display them.

Comment: Output ```printf``` isn't the problem. 
The problem is that **dest** contains 1 character in the result

Comment: The base64-encoded string `"SABlAGwAbABvAA=="` decodes to the hex dump 48 00 65 00 6c 00 6c 00 6f 00, equivalent to the contents of the (ASCII-encoded) C string literal `"H\0e\0l\0l\0o\0" (copied to the `dest` buffer with an additional null terminator on the end). The `printf("Decode: %s", dest);` will only print the contents of `dest` up to the first encountered null character, which is in `dest[1]`. So only the first character is printed.

Comment: @IanAbbott 
Please tell me how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

The reason only the first character was decoded is because the second character starts with a 0x00 byte, so the call to `strlen()` (which is only for ascii strings) returned a very small number (like 1 or 2) rather than the actual length of the string.

suggest becoming familiar with the `wchar_t` type and the functions to handle wide characters, like: `wprintf()` and the 'wide' modifier for strings: `-L` and the header file: `wchar.h`

[how to handle wide character strings](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wprintf-and-wscanf-in-c-library)

Answer (score 0):

You are not working with `C` strings here, so stay away from using string functions such as `strlen();`

And consider using `unsigned char` as the type for the array

```
unsigned char base64decode{} = {...
```

In this case, the number of array elements can be determined by the statement:

```
size_t len = sizeof(base64decode_lut)/sizeof(base64decode_lut[0]);
```